# cast PyArrayObject* to int* fails

Tags: c++, c, arrays, numpy, casting

I have a very quick question. Anyone could please explain me why when I pass a Numpy array of integers to my C code then I cannot retrieve the correct values? My guess is that `int` type in C is not the same of default Numpy, but I frankly got lost in the online docs. Here is my case:

In the Python module I have a dictionary

```
from numpy import * 

pars = {...,
        'ICs' : array([0,1,2])
       }
```

Then I pass this dictionary to my C function as

```
#include <Python.h>
#include <numpy/arrayobject.h>

...
...
int main(){
    int i, *ics;

    //That is the assignment according to the manual 
    ics = (int*)((PyArrayObject*)PyDict_GetItemString(pardict,"ICs"))->data);
    for(i=0;i<9;i++) printf("\ni=%d\t-->%d",i,ics[i]);   
    return 0;     
}
```

Then upon execution, what I get is:

```
i=0-->0
i=1-->0
i=2-->1
i=3-->0
i=4-->2
i=5-->0
i=6-->9102
i=7-->-289
i=8-->2910103
i=9-->294921
```

I would have expected to see instead my three integers to be printed for `i<3`. Any clarification would be appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe you just need a bigger `int`? Try `int64_t`.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz Yes it's a problem of data types indeed, since if I specified `"ICs" : array([0,2,3], dtype=intc)` the output is correct (just found out). But do I really need to specify every time the `int` (or even the `double` type!?!) that I am using in Numpy in order to handle those data correctly in C/C++? I thought that the two data types were considered by default in Python were readable in C/C++ as well.

Comment: @maurizion it seems pretty obvious to me that the type you want in C++ must match the type that's returned from python. You could perhaps wrap it in a routine that returns `variant` of different array types and checks the python value before choosing, if that would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the proper function to get an access to the underlying array, namely `PyArray_BYTES`, as described in http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/c-api.array.html.

Beware however that this gives a direct access to the buffer, without taking into account strides!